# Insert row at a specific ID Room Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, caching, android-room

I am trying to insert a row at a specific ID using Android's SQLite wrapper, Room.

Basically, the use case is I get a row of data from a server and I want to use the remote row's ID as the primary key for the locally stored row in Room.

The code:

```
@Entity
class UserModel {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;

    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
}
```

---

```
@Dao
public interface UserDAO {

    /**
     * Select all Users from the User table.
     *
     * @return all users.
     */
    @Query("SELECT * FROM " + UserRoomDB.TABLE_NAME)
    UserModel getUser();


    /**
     * Insert a user in the database. If the user already exists, replace it.
     *
     * @param user the user to be inserted.
     */
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertUser(UserModel user);

    /**
     * Update a user.
     *
     * @param user task to be updated
     * @return the number of users updated. This should always be 1.
     */
    @Update
    int updateUser(UserModel user);

}
```

---

```
private void cacheUser(UserModel userModel){
        UserRoomDB db = Room.databaseBuilder(this.appContext,
                UserRoomDB.class, UserRoomDB.DB_NAME).build();
        db.userDAO().insertUser(userModel);
}
```

Comment: adding some code will be good.

Comment: @Sree I added my code. The userModel has the correct Id but then when I go to get the user it is not stored at that id

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want the data coming from remote server and set the response's `id` received from there onto your local database's row.

If that is what you want then in addition to setting `@PrimaryKey`  annotation on your `UserModel` you should also specify `autoGenerate` to false.

```
@Entity
class UserModel {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    public int id;

    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
}
```

Doing this your ids wont get autoGenerated by Room and you can set the id right after getting them from the remote source and then call the DAO's `insertUser()` function using the current `UserModel` object.